# Local Messaging in SILVERLIGHT 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have to implement Local Messaging in our silverlight4 project.

Please suggest to me some good websites,blogs and video tutorials on **local messaging 
in Silverlight 4.**

In our project we have 7 XAP files.

Regards,
JN

Answer (score 0):

This post is in Danish and contains samples in Silverlight 2 using javascript and in Silverlight 3 using the message system (the one you want!). Let me know if it fits your needs.
http://xamlgeek.net/2009/08/18/kommunikation-mellem-silverlight-applikationer/